# Boost Regex not matching

Tags: regex, boost

I've got a string i need to match:

```
/sw/unicad/C32_SC_12_CLKPBP10_LR/2.0/CADENCE/LEF/C32_SC_12_CLKPBP10_LR_soc.lef
```

I've come up with

```
static const boost::regex lefFilePath("/?(([[:word:]]*)/)*([[:word:]]*)\.lef");
```

Yet it doesn't match. Can I get a hand please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the dot in `2.0` isn't matched by the `[:word:]` shorthand, so you need to include it in the character class.

You probably also should escape the backslash.

Try this:

```
static const boost::regex lefFilePath("/?(([[:word:].]*)/)*([[:word:].]*)\\.lef");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a `2.0` in your string, the `.` is not in the [[:word:]] character class.

The square brackets are defining character classes and you can add the characters you want to be included in that class. So please try

```
[[:word:].]
```

The `.` is treated literally inside a character class, so you don't need to escape it there.